# operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I've created a class myString and I'm trying to run the following code:

```
class myString{
    char* str;
    int len;

public:
    myString(char* str1 = " "){
        len = strlen(str1);
        str = new char[len+1];
        strcpy(str, str1);
    };

    int getLen() const {
        return len;
    };

    char* getString() const {
        return str;
    };

    ~myString(){
        delete[] str;
    };

    myString& operator=(myString& orig){
        cout << "hello";
        if (str == NULL){
            delete[] str;
        };
        str = new char[orig.getLen()];
        strcpy(str, orig.getString());
        cout << this << endl;
        return *this;
    };

    ...
};



int main(){


    myString s("bla");
    myString k("dingo");
        myString g = s;
        // s=k;  //When this line is commented I get a linking error
         ...
   };
```

My Questions:

1. Why "hello" does not get printed?
2. Why the line `s=k` causes a linker error?

This is the error:

> LINK : c:\users\perry\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\inheritance\Debug\inheritance.exe not found or not built
>   by the last incremental link; performing full link 1>main.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl
>   operator<<(class std::basic_ostream
>
> > &,class myString *)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@PAVmyString@@@Z)
> >     referenced in function "public: class myString & __thiscall
> >     myString::operator=(class myString &)" (??4myString@@QAEAAV0@AAV0@@Z)
> >     1>c:\users\perry\documents\visual studio
> >     2010\Projects\inheritance\Debug\inheritance.exe : fatal error LNK1120:
> >     1 unresolved externals

Thanks,
Li

Comment: You need to look up the rule of three (or is four). Anyway a correct assignment operator and copy constructor are needed (copy constructor is missing and assignment operator declaration is not what I would call standard (And the implementation is buggy (of by one error in len))). While you are at it look up the copy and swap idium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the following, you need a copy constructor. It does not use the assignment operator function.

```
myString g = s;
```

**Edit**

For the linker error - I can't help you with that. Rather than guessing at what `operator<<` that line calls, I will just give up on this because you haven't provided the code. In normal C++ code, there is no way that a simple `cout << this;` would cause a linker error. `cout` has an operator that accepts a `void const*` for this. You have declared an operator somewhere that provides a better match but did not define it.

Comment: @pm100 a default one is generated

Comment: Thanks. I will add the copy constructor. Any idea about the linking error?

Comment: so what does happen when g = s executes? and why is s=k treated differently by the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Link error is that you have not defined

```
operator<<(class std::basic_ostream< >  &,class myString *)
```

due to the line

```
cout << this << endl;
```

Comment: interesting that it compiles but fails to link. I would have thought it would fail to compile

Comment: not sure if it is just MSVC, but it often takes the first use of a method if it is unknown as the default definition which can hide the compilation issue of using something that is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
operator=(const myString &orig)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myString g = s;
```

This doesn't call operator=, but the copy constructor. Since you have not defined any copy constructor, a default one is generated, copying all fields. But you're holding pointers, you don't want that to happen ! That's why you need a copy constructor.

About the linking error:

```
cout << this << endl;
```

Here, you try to use `operator<<` with this. The type of this is `myString*`, for which this operator is not defined. If you want to print the value of the this pointer, you can convert it:

```
cout << (void*) this << endl;
```

```
 if (str == NULL){
                delete[] str;
            };
```

You want `if (str != NULL)` here (typo ?).

Comment: Woohoo!!! Thanks, that (void*) saved my night. thank you very much. For some reason when I see those linking errors I freak out. I have to start reading them more carefully. Thanks!!!

Comment: By the way, the NULL check is unnecessary. It's well-defined and legal to `delete NULL` or `delete[] NULL`. Nothing happens. And also you don't need semi-colons at the end of function blocks or conditional (if) blocks -- only after class and struct definitions (and statements, of course!)

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, `myString g = s;` is the initialization of a new `myString`, and that's done with the copy constructor (which is automatically provided because you didn't write one).

The link error is because of the line `cout << this << endl;`, since you haven't told the system how to print `this`, and it apparently can't come up with a way.

In C++, there's the Rule of Three:  if you write a copy constructor, assignment operator, or destructor, you probably need to write all three.  (The exception is writing a virtual destructor for a base class.)  Typically, then, your class manages some resource (`str` in your case), and you need to handle it in all three cases.

Also, use `const` when you can.  You can pass a non-`const` variable into a `const` reference, but not vice versa.

Your destructor is fine.  Your assignment operator should have the signature `myString & operator=(const &myString)`, and your copy constructor should have the signature `myString::myString(const &myString)`.